# Disabling TDE on AlwaysOn database

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, transparent-data-encryption

Which are the correct steps to disable (not removing) `TDE` on a `AlwaysOn` database in an availability group?

I found steps for removing `TDE` but that involves removing the availability group and disabling the `AlwaysOn` relationship. I hope this is only for removing at all the `TDE` configuration.

Comment: just want to disable, with "set encryption off", in standalone configuration is enough and all TDE configuration can remain on server if in the future TDE on database must be anbled again. Want to know if is possible to disable without acting on group because the group contains other databases that are not the scope of TDE

Comment: Could you post the steps you found for removing TDE?

Comment: you can find them at this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3d2e2440-7c3e-4d0f-923c-f16cb8ae53b1/steps-to-remove-tde-on-alwayson?forum=sqlsecurity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable TDE you must first remove the candidate database from the Availability Group - the group itself however does not need to be dropped.

To do this, the following code is needed:

```
USE [master];
GO

ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET HADR OFF;
GO
```

Once this is complete, you may then disable TDE on the PRIMARY replica:

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET ENCRYPTION OFF;
```

The process of decryption is asynchronous, and can be monitored by looking at the *percent_complete* column in the *sys.dm_database_encryption_keys* DMV

One thing to note, is that although the database itself is encrypted, if you aren't careful you can end up with part of the log file still encrypted - this is only a problem if you will be dropping the encryption certificates from the offending servers, or trying to take a backup and restore this database to a server that doesn't hold this encryption certificate.

Comment: You don't have to take a database out of the Availability Group in order to disable the TDE.